# Apply multiple actions to one selector

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$('img, a').Tooltip( ... );
$('img, a').data( ... );
$('img, a').on( ... );
```

Is it possible in JQuery to do something like:

```
$('img, a') {
  .Tooltip( ... );
  .data( ... );
  .on( ... );
}
```

So basically declare the selector only once ...

Comment: Yes, you can chain events.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: Start here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can chain, use the following syntax:

```
$('img, a').Tooltip( ... ).data( ... ).on( ... );
```